# Checkout City Dropdown Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, address, drop-downs, city

please I am trying to add specific cities to which my shipping carrier destination and make them dropdown in my plugin.

This is my code so far but it's not working and I get Exception #0 (LogicException): ClicknShip\Module\Block\Checkoutmod\Checkoutmod does not implement BlockInterface.

this is checkout_index_index.html

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="ClicknShip\Module\Block\Checkoutmod\Checkoutmod" name="Checkoutmod_Checkoutmod" after="checkout.cart.coupon" template="ClicknShip_Module::checkout/cart/Checkoutmod.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Lastly, I have checkoutmod.phtml

getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                
                    
                                              
                                test1
                                test2

```
    </form>         
</div>
```

Here is my Checkoutmod class

getCities();
        $options = '';
        foreach($cities as $city){
            $isSelected = $selectedCity == $city ? ' selected="selected"' : null;
            $options .= '' . $city . '';
        }
        return $options;
    }
}

Please help